# Using the jquery html() function

Tags: jquery, html

I have a paragraph

```
<p>hello<br>wor&nbsp;l&nbsp;d</p>
```

then I want show the paragraph's html in another textarea use jquery html() method

```
    $(function () {
        var temp = $('p').html();

        $("textarea").html(temp);
    });
```

but the result is

`hello<br>wor l d`

Why does `<br>` not work? I didn't change any html.

[Here is the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/7s6v8/)

Comment: Are you after displaying the *html source* from the paragraph's contents, or showing it with `&nbsp;` and `<br>` *rendered as space and line break*?

Comment: @Tomas Lycken:yes,I still want the line break,cuz I want the the mark  write to the sql,so when next time I want read from the sql,it would keep as it original look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

? isn´t that clear? you are requesting the html and this one is pasted into the textbox? You will have to replace the br into linebrakes, like "\n"

```
var temp = $('p').html();

 $("#tt").html(temp.replace(/<br\s*(\/|)>/gi, '\n'));
```

Comment: Use `temp.replace(/<br\s*(\/|)>/gi, '\n')` to catch 'em all.

Comment: thanks DarthJDG, but from now on, we should also say (since it begins to look not like a "fast" answer anymore) that this method replaces only once, right?

Comment: With the regex's `gi` flags set, it replaces all occurrences and it's doing a case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

A textarea simply displays text, not formatted HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to output it as displayed, the following code should help:

```
$(function() {
    var temp = $('p').html();
    var textareaval = temp.replace("<br>", "\n");
    textareaval = textareaval.replace("<br />", "\n");
    $('textarea').html(textareaval);
});
```

See the jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6adgA/